# How to uniquely identify email reply?

Tags: email, sendgrid

I am building a ticketing system where users can raise a support ticket and agents can reply to the particular ticket and when the agent replied to a particular ticket I will send the reply to respective user email (email service using SendGrid).

My question is when the user replied to the agent email I will fetch that email with SendGrid inbound parser but I am stuck that how to uniquely identify for which ticket user has replied. I have two ideas attaching `JWT` in the header or unique email address resemble ticket id (`ticket-id-2654654@example.com`) but I don't what will work

Answer (score 4):

You could send a custom [Message-ID Header](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Message-ID) ([RFC 2392](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2392)) with your E-Mail. Responses to your E-Mail should then contain a `References` and/or `In-Reply-To` header containing the `Message-ID` of the E-Mail that was answered.

Edit: Just tested it with Zendesk and Zammad. They both seem to identify responses in that way.

Comment: any chance you know how to get that message-id from sendgrid? or is there a way i can know it myself?

Comment: @steinfeld, One way is to use Regex to get it after getting the header in the inbound parse 

https://github.com/shammelburg/express-sendgrid-inbound-parse/blob/main/index.js#L28

Check above for example in JS

Comment: @MysteriousPerson Do message IDs change automatically at all even if you set them? What about multiple replies in a row for example?

Answer (score 2):

You mention having a unique email address, not unlike a [VERP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable_envelope_return_path) (*Variable Envelope Return Path*) address. VERP is most pertinent if it's dealing with bounces, since it refers to the address used for the SMTP `MAIL FROM:`,

```
MAIL FROM:<ticket-id-2654654@example.com>
```

in particular it is helpful to identify which emails bounce - the email likely never arrives in a mailbox at the remote end. Note that the address used during the SMTP conversation like this will be recorded at the top of the received email with a 'Return-Path:' header.

Assuming an email doesn't bounce then how to ensure an email with a recognisable identifier comes back:

MysteriousPerson's custom `Message-ID:` header suggestion is excellent; also specify a VERP address in a `Reply-To:` header - so one or both of the identifiers you put there should be found in the reply to decode which ticket/user the original message was sent to. You have the choice of using the same VERP address in the `From:` header or something more human-friendly, depending on what you want the recipient to see. Since `Reply-To:` is specified, client software will use that for replies.

The main RFCs on [SMTP](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5321) and [message format](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5322) are likely to be helpful if you're not already aware of them.